# Closure can be eliminated: method has overload to avoid closure creation

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, rider

JetBrains Rider suggests the following over `Disposable.Create`:

> Closure can be eliminated: method has overload to avoid closure creation

How do I fix it?

```cs
public sealed class RedisSubscriber<TKey, TMessage> : IBusSubscriber<TKey, TMessage>
{
    private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;
    private readonly IRedisSerializer _serializer;

    public RedisSubscriber(IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer, IRedisSerializer serializer)
    {
        _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;
        _serializer = serializer;
    }

    public IObservable<RedisValue> SubscribeAsync(TKey key)
    {
        var channel = CreateChannel(key);
        var subscriber = _connectionMultiplexer.GetSubscriber();

        return Observable.Create<RedisValue>(observer =>
        {
            subscriber.SubscribeAsync(channel, (redisChannel, redisValue) =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redisValue))
                {
                    return;
                }

                observer.OnNext(redisValue);
            });
            return Disposable.Create(() => subscriber.Unsubscribe(channel));
        });
    }

    private RedisChannel CreateChannel(TKey key)
    {
        return key switch
        {
            string s => new RedisChannel(s, RedisChannel.PatternMode.Auto),
            byte[] v => new RedisChannel(v, RedisChannel.PatternMode.Auto),
            _ => new RedisChannel(_serializer.Serialize(key), RedisChannel.PatternMode.Literal)
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disposable.Create` has an overload with a signature of `Disposable.Create(TState, Action<TState> action)`. This overload allows you to pass in your state. In your case, you are using `subscriber` and `channel` in your `Disposable.Create` method. If you don't pass in `subscriber` or `channel` to your delegate, it will create a closure to capture those references.

So in order to avoid a closure getting created, you need to use the overload as Rider suggests. To do that, you can do something along the lines of

```cs
Disposable.Create((subscriber, channel), x => x.subscriber.Unsubscribe(x.channel));
```